# Possible to add "Find in Files" through Notepad++ or other program to context menu (windows 10)

Tags: windows, notepad++

I use the "Find in Files" feature of notepad++ all the time, but its bothersome having to open notepad++, browse to the directory, open search in N++, then copy directory name to it, then search

Is there a program that will allow this process to be automated down to right clicking on a directory in context menu and selecting find in files?

Thanks

Comment: not perhaps quite what you're after but I find that Agent Ransack (Mythicsoft.) is really good for this sort of operation and it has the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to accomplish this task:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String?view=powershell-5.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Relevant bit:

> This example searches a directory and all of its subdirectories for a specific text string.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\System32\*.txt -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'Microsoft' -CaseSensitive
```

> Get-ChildItem uses the Path parameter to specify C:\Windows\System32\*.txt. The Recurse parameter includes the subdirectories. The objects are sent down the pipeline to Select-String.
>
> Select-String uses the Pattern parameter and specifies the string Microsoft. The CaseSensitive parameter is used to match the exact case of the string. Select-String displays the output in the PowerShell console.